# Running a self-contained exe without deps.json

Tags: .net-core, configuration-files, self-contained

I have a net5.0 app that's self-contained. I do not need the deps.json file since all of my dependencies exist already in the output folder so I removed the file with `<GenerateDependencyFile>false</GenerateDependencyFile>`. However, whenever I run my application I get the following message:

```
Cannot use file stream for [myapp.deps.json]: No such file or directory
```

The program itself runs fine as I expected but is there a way for me to remove this message somehow?

Edit: Also wanted to mention that we have a little hack that prevents the use of deps.json and that's another reason why I need it removed.

Comment: Have you published or are you using the .exe that gets generated when you build?

Comment: I used MSBuild to build the project, which to my understanding runs publish during the process. So it should be published.